# WPF datagrid add text

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have tabControl.In TabItem I have datagrid. In event SelectionChanged I need to see different text in datagrid on TabItem.

This I add:

```
System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid dataGrid = new System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid();
DataGridTextColumn textColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
textColumn.Width = 200;
textColumn.Header = "Account";
textColumn.Binding = new Binding("Account");
dataGrid.Columns.Add(textColumn);

item.Content = dataGrid;

tabControl1.Items.Add(item);
```

I need for example this:

```
tabControl1.Controls[0].Items.Add(new DataItem());
```

Comment: How add text to dataGrid but dataGrid can be 10-20.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use WPF like it is windows Forms, but it is *very* different. You will find out all that you need to be able to use a `DataGrid` in the [`DataGrid` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx) page on MSDN.

In short, you need to create a public property for your collection of data and bind it to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property as shown in this example adapted from the linked page on MSDN:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding yourCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name"  Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" />
        <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="Email" Binding="{Binding Email}"  
            ContentBinding="{Binding Email, Converter={StaticResource 
            EmailConverter}}" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Member?" Binding="{Binding IsMember}" />
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Order Status"  SelectedItemBinding="{Binding 
             Status}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myEnum}}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

You can then define your required columns as in this example.

Comment: I add datagrid on TabItems dynamically. I need add text to datagrid programmly.

Comment: Simple solution... don't do that... either do it properly (in XAML), or just use WinForms to do it.